# Approach towards unread messages

Tags: jquery, asp.net, sql

I will be having a list of messages(as hyperlink) in the ul li design which will represents the messages sent to me. There is a column isread in my database which represents whether I have read my message or not. Now here comes my question.. When user clicks on the messages in that list I want the isread column to be set as 1. Right now I am thinking to fire an ajax request to server to make it 1 when user clicks the link in that list and when I receive response from server I am going to transfer the the user to the location of navigate url present in that list. Am I going right? is there any better approach?

Comment: Why keep the user waiting for the ajax submit and response? Why not update the database in the page load of the navigate URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Opening message will take some time. That time will be increased for the time necessary to get response from server.
I would open message immediately and then when message is open send notification to the server.

Also add "Make message unread" command.

See Gmail for example.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can store the date of visiting, you may need it on the future for statistics, etc.
and for making querys= if a row has the "visited" field on null, it has been never visited. Else, it has been visited on the stored date.

Answer (score 0):

Why wait for confirmation of the read-flag change, does it really matter? Presumably you will have to run a query to fetch the message so why not update the flag or increment a view count at the same time?